# woocommerce_get_item_data only returns the last item in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am having a weired situation with creating customer-defined product fields for the WooCommerce.

I was able to create the field and the data is passed to the cart and check out process. The problem is, that custom field is being added to ALL product in my cart OR REMOVED completely if I add another product that does not have a custom field.

For example, say I have 3 product in my system. Product A & C has no custom field, product B has custom field. If I add product A & B to cart, both A & B will have the custom field from product B attached to it. If I then add product C to cart, it will now erase all the associated custom field for product A, B, and C. In other words, even if I only have one product that has this custom field available, if I have 3 product in my cart, all 3 of them will have the custom field value attached to it on the cart page.

As I continue to check out screen, it is displaying the custom fields to the right product properly. Only in cart page that it shows the custom fields for ALL products.

I am using using the woocommerce_get_item_data as my reference function. My filter code look like this:

```
function display_schedule_text_cart( $item_data, $cart_item ) {

    //var_dump($cart_item);
    $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    if ( empty( $cart_item['class-1'] )) {
        return $item_data;
    }

    $class_dates = explode("|", wc_clean( $cart_item['class-1']));
    $values = "<ul>";
    foreach ($class_dates AS $v){
        $values .= "<li>".$v."</li>";
    }
    $values .= "</ul>";

    $item_data[] = array(
        'key'     => __( 'Class Dates: ', 'class-1' ),
        'value'   => $values,
        'display' => '',
    );
    return $item_data;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_schedule_text_cart', 10, 2 );
```

The problem seems to be when I do var_dump on $cart_item, on cart item table on the cart page, it always returns the last item in my cart instead of the correct item of that item cell. (and item_data is always empty).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help  must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. So please **edit your question and add all needed related code**. With your actual question explanation and code, is not possible to test anything. We can't guess things by magic.Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Here are two products to test:

Product A (No custom fields): http://www.realtorsacademy.com.php56-28.lan3-1.websitetestlink.com/product/principles-of-real-estate-1-3-day-weekend-20180309-730-am/

Product B (with custom fields): http://www.realtorsacademy.com.php56-28.lan3-1.websitetestlink.com/product/qualifying-courses-bundle/

Theoretically, only product B should have dates listed on cart page. But if you add A first then B, you will see that both A & B has the dates included in the cart page.  If you add B first then A, then you will notice there is no dates on either product.